# fadeToggle just one li item

Tags: jquery, css

I'm loading a submenu into another page with the .load() function and I want to have an accordian fade-y dropdown. I need it to select just one ul list directly under the title, not all the lists! P.S I don't know why I need the ("html"),mouseenter (I replaced the .ready because I had to click the button twice but this just responds when when mouse goes over it, my bandaid) If someone could explain that I would appreciate it too, because I don't really like it.

```
$('html').mouseenter(function() {

 $('#submenu.left li h2').click(function() {    
    var  button = $('#submenu.left li h2');
    var  toggle = $('#submenu.left #dropdown'); 
    if ( !toggle.is(':animated')) {$(toggle).fadeToggle('slow');}

     });
 });
```

});

Thanks!

Comment: If you can setup a http://jsfiddle.net with your double click bugged code. I am sure someone can correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting a particular element in a jQuery object you can use .eq( index )

see here: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: ok but I want it so that it's not so implicit. because a random client might change the lists. Basically not picking a specific one, but just making sure the one I'm picking is the only one picked.I kinda thought a toggle would do that. Sur it works for just one...but as soon as you have more lists...then all of them toggle. it's almost like I want to toggle the toggles~do I have to do some kind of for loop?

Comment: hmm in that case I'm not sure quite what you're trying to achieve here, as Huangism suggested setup and like a jsfiddle.net, it might make things clearer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vsgtj/5/

It's not perfect but I decided to put everything possible in so you can see everything going on. the reason for so many classes is so that no matter what page I land on it will load the same menu that goes with it. so as you can see, both lists expand but I only want one at a time, and since there are many menus, not just this one...

http://jsfiddle.net/Vsgtj/5/

Comment: I'm sure there is a much better solution than mine, but this one is quick, http://jsfiddle.net/LjUJv/, for future reference you should use classes instead of ids, ids should be unique. What I'm doing here is selecting the parent li of the h2 element then finding the #dropdown container.

Comment: ok I'll give that a shot. Our testing server is down right now. but actually this looks right, like what I wanted. I guess I just am still unsure how to use "this" but it seemed like I should have done that. and it works on JSFiddle, so good enough. Why don't you think this is the best solution? it's good enough for me if it works and isn't over redundant. A soon as I can test it on the server, I'll give you credit for helping me solve this.

Comment: I just don't like going through multiple parents to get to the li, but it'll work just fine.

Comment: ok I see. Yes it's wild. It's all because I have to work with a template and put stuff inside the stuff. If you know what that's about. thanks! well I guess our server is still down, but I'll just consider this solved because I'm reading up on .parent() and I probably will be able to figure it out.